# Using an attribute to update an object passed as a parameter

Tags: c#, .net, attributes

I have done a bit with C# method attributes but I have not done something that covers this requirement, and I am not even sure it is possible but here goes.

Let say I have a class like..

```
public class MyObject
{
   public DateTime? TheTime {get;set;}
   public string AValue {get;set;}
}
```

And a function like this...

```
public void AddObject(MyObject mo)
{
   //Do Something
}
```

Now, when the object is passed AValue will be set, but TheTime will be null (as this needs to be set in the AddObject method). I can do this like...

```
public void AddObject(MyObject mo)
{
   mo.TheTime = DateTime.Now;
   //Do Something
}
```

But I don't like that, what I want is to create an attribute that will do the job for me. So ultimately, I want something like this

```
[AutoUpdate(Parameter = "mo")]
public void AddObject(MyObject mo)
{
   //Do Something
}
```

and the magic is done for me.

Any ideas on how to create an attribute to do this? A simple link would do, I can't seem to find what I am looking for at the minute

Comment: I am not sure I understand why you need the complicated attribute solution. Is there any reason why you can't just make the setter of AValue update the datetime field when it is set or something along those lines? Or indeed do stuff in the constructor of your object. I don't even see how your attribute would work without having the `mo.TheTime = DateTime.Now` line of code somewhere or is it a case of refactoring it out of many methods?

Comment: @Chris, No refactoring to be done. The layer that sets AValue should not be concerned with TheTime. It is the AddObject functions task to care about it. There are also a few other standard properties it needs to care about too. It cannot be done at contruction as this is again not the job of the function calling code. There is more than one common property that needs to be updated this way. I think for now I will add a helper function that does the update (as like the code would for my attribute) and then I can at least limit this to one function call at the start of AddObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a cross-cutting concerns library ([AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming)), which applies a [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) around your method, allowing you to inject functionality via attributes. It's usually used for things like logging.

Take a look at [Spring.Net](http://www.springframework.net/) or [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/container/).

A a quick example of decorator pattern to create your own implementation.

```
public class MyExtendedClass : IMyClass
{
    public MyExtendedClass(IMyClass myClass)
    {
        this.innerMyClass= myClass;
    }

    public void AddObject(MyObject mo)
    {
       // does mo have an attribute on AddObject
       // if so
       Type clsType = innerMyClass.GetType();
       MethodInfo mInfo = clsType.GetMethod("AddObject");
       if (Attribute.IsDefined(mInfo, typeof(AutoUpdateAttribute)))
       {
          mo.TheTime = DateTime.Now;
       }
       innerMyClass.AddObject(mo);
    } 
}
```

Then use like this:

```
IMyClass myClass = new MyExtendedClass(new MyClass());
myClass.AddObject(mo);
```

Comment: Thanks for the links, and I will take a look, but I do not want to use any 3rd party apps for this. I would like to create this attribute myself

Comment: Creating the attribute is fine, but need need some engine behind it to invoke it. You can do this with a decorator yourself, which is all the more easier if you are using a IoC container.

Comment: OK, I think I see what you mean. I have used MVC ActionFilterAttributes before and I guess these are setup to do the "extra work" you speak of as they have some useful methods that can be overridden. We are actually using PostSharp for some other stuff and I guess this would work for what I need. Was hoping to be able to create myself though, so I think I will give it a go and see how I get on. Thanks for the information